# Do Google Compute Engine VMs startup on a different physical host after the VM is stopped and started?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In AWS for example, when an instance is stopped and then started, it switches between physical hosts.

> When you stop an EBS boot instance you are giving up the physical hardware that the server was running on and EC2 is free to start somebody else’s instance there.
>
> Your EBS boot volume (and other attached EBS volumes) are still preserved, though they aren’t really tied to a physical or virtual server. They are just associated with an instance id that isn’t running anywhere.
>
> When you start the instance again, EC2 picks some hardware to run it on, ties in the EBS volume(s) and boots it up again.
>
> Things that change when you stop/start include:
>
> New internal IP address, though could randomly be the same. [VPC instances keep same internal IP addresses through stop/start.]
>
> New external IP address (though could randomly be the same).
>
> If an Elastic IP address was associated with the instance before it was stopped, then you’ll need to re-associate it after the start. [VPC instances keep Elastic IP addresses associated through stop/start.]
>
> Any contents on the instance’s former ephemeral storage were wiped and you are given fresh ephemeral storage (often mounted as /mnt).
>
> You can leave an instance stopped for as long as you like and not get charged for run time (though you do get charged at a much lower rate for the EBS volume storage). See the next point.
>
> A fresh billing hour is started for the instance when you start it again. E.g., if you start a new instance and then stop/start it 3 times within the first 60 minutes, you’ll get charged for 4 hours instead of 1.
>
> There is a small chance that EC2 will not have available slots of the correct instance type to run your instance when you want to start it again. I’ve had this happen and temporarily switched to a different, available instance type to get it running again.
>
> When you reboot, it’s a simple reboot at the OS level and the instance stays running on the same hardware, with the same private and public IP addresses, keeps the same Elastic IP address (if associated), and keeps the same ephemeral storage without getting wiped. No new billing hour is started on a reboot and you do not give up the instance hardware.

[Source - https://alestic.com/2011/09/ec2-reboot-stop-start/](https://alestic.com/2011/09/ec2-reboot-stop-start/)

So, if a physical host is degraded or will undergo future maintenance, one simply needs to gracefully stop an instance and then start it back up and it would have moved onto a different physical host (not always guaranteed but generally true).

Restarting an AWS instance keeps the VM running on the same physical host.

Could someone clarify how Google Compute Engine VMs behave when an instance is stopped / started and when it is restarted?

I raised this as a query in a ticket we had with GCP but got directed to the following two documentation URLs which doesn't really answer the question:

- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#stopping_an_instance
- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration

The context behind why I am rasing this question is to find out whether or not our VM continues to run on the same physical host after GCP automatically restarted the VM due to a hosterror.

Answer (score 2):

When a hosterror occurs means that the physical machine where your VM is located had a hardware or software issue and that causes a hosterror. If you have the VM set to automatically restart, which is the default value, your VM will be restarted on a different physical machine.

You can check it on our public documentation on https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#hosterror

When you perform a stop operation on a VM, Compute Engine send the ACPI Power Off signal to the instance. When a VM is stopped the Ephemeral external IP addresses are released from the instance and you pay for resources that still attached to the VM instance such as static IPs and persistent disk data.

When you start a stopped VM it may be allocated on another physical machine or on the same physical machine.

When you perform a reset operation on a VM, is similar to doing a hard reset on your computer where you might press a reset button or press and hold the power button. Resetting an instance wipes the memory contents of the machine and resets the virtual machine to its initial state. The reset operation retains its ephemeral IP address, its persistent disk, its machine type, and so on. However, any data stored in memory will be reset unless you back up the data.

You can check the instance life cycle on our public documentation on https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/instance-life-cycle

Comment: Thank you for that link with confirmation that the VM was restarted on a different physical host when a hosterror is encountered. I will leave the question open to address the main query as to what happens during a stop/start and a restart.